# simple maths with image data in javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to understand how to do some basic operations on image data in javascript. In the following code snippet I have some data, called imgData, and when I send imgData.length to the console I get 1032000 which is correct. The image is 600x430 and 600x430x4=1032000. However, I am trying to sum the R values. When I do this I get 20 which can't possibly be right. Is this something to do with the fact that the image data are uint8 type?

```
  imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, srcImage.width, srcImage.height);
  var i;
  var sumR;
  sumR = 0;
  console.log(imgData.data.length);
  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    sumR = sumR = imgData.data[i];
  }
  console.log(sumR);
```

Comment: Typo: should be `+` instead of `=`. Debugging helps... Step through your code, inspect variables... etc.

Comment: Doh - sorry for being so dumb. It works perfectly now. Thanks for your patience trincot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) helpfully pointed out, the issue was a typo:  `+` instead of `=`.